# Set custom metadata when audio is playing (Control Centre, Lockscreen...)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uiwebview, mpmediaitem

**Summary**

I am currently trying to set an app-wide default metadata for every time it plays audio. Currently, only the URL of the audio streaming is shown on the Control Centre and the Lockscreen. I am trying to my own custom values; however, I can't get it to work. It may be worth noting that the audio is playing through a `UIWebView`.

(Continued below screenshot)

[image: Screenshot]

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var mPlayer: MPMediaItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let image = UIImage(named: "Artwork")!
        let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
                return image
            })

        let nowPlaying: NSDictionary = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Song",
                                        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Artist",
                                        MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork]

        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlaying as? [String : Any]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the MPMediaItemArtwork with its initializer

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Artwork")!
let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
    return image
})
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I edited the code to show your improvements. Now, is there any reason as to why it's still showing the streaming URL instead of the given `nowPlayingInfo`?

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working by putting the code under the `applicationDidEnterBackground` function.